# <Component {...{myProp : this.props.myProps}} /> vs <Component myProp={this.props.myProps} />;

Tags: reactjs

I am in a app where I just start and I am trying to understand what the difference is with that syntax, what are the approaches

`<Component {...{myProp : this.props.myProps}} />`

vs

`<Component myProp={this.props.myProps} />`

Answer (score 5):

The difference between your two approaches is in the first one you pass *n* props implicitly. In the second you pass props explicitly.

The operator is called the spread, `...`, operator, in the React world it unpacks an array or object into keyworded arguments, `prop={value}`.
In JavaScript only world it can only unpack arrays.

This means that React wants to render this:

```
<Component myProp={this.props.myProps} />
```

when faced with

```
<Component {...{myProp : this.props.myProps}} />
```

There is no difference, in output, between your two approaches in your example but differs greatly when faced with a more real example of the `props` structure.

Either you pass some props explicitly

```
this.props = {
    myProp: 1,
    otherProps: 'limelights'
}

<Component myProps={this.props.myProp} myOtherProp={this.props.otherProp} />
```

or you pass all of them regardless and letting the `Component` deal with the incoming props anyway it wants to.

```
<Component {...this.props} />
```

Comment: Yep. The spread notation is great when the exact combination of props is unknown until runtime.